# Fall away (meaning)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I would like to know the meaning of the phrasal verb "*to fall away*" in the following context.

Examples:

> 1. After I got that big promotion, I found that a lot of my old friends at work fell away.
> 2. After the divorce, all his friends fell away one by one.

Comment: They *disappeared* because you were no longer in their scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fall away**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20away) is a specific verbal phrase:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *intransitive verb*
>   **1 a** : to withdraw friendship or support
>   **1 b** : to renounce one's faith
>   **2 a** : to diminish gradually in size
>   **2 b** : to drift off a course

The examples in the question are covered by the first sense in this definition—the lessening of a friendship, or losing touch with someone.

Answer (score 1):

In this usage, "fell away" means that they have moved or dropped out of your social circle.

'Fell' is the past tense of 'fall.' In this case the definition is

: a falling out, off, or away : DROPPING

[Meriam-Webster - Fall](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall)